# Separating std::threads by condtions

Tags: multithreading, c++11, concurrency

Program to invoke threads on the priority basis

I am trying to run threads as priority 1 and other priority threads(except 1),

In here thread t2 is of priority 2  the 3 threads t1,t2, and t3 are in wait . and thread t4 goes and calls signals with priority 2. //- **I want it to invoke only threads with priority other than 1**

**The output of this program is**

single notifyall
both notifyall
cv.wait(master);
priority1
cv1.wait(master);
priority2
cv.wait(master);
priority1

which is what I expected , I am looking for the eplanation of this behavious as I am of a view that notify_all() will notify all threads so all threads should get notify no the priority 1 threads or the other priority threads

````
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::condition_variable cv1;
std::mutex cv_m; 
 
void waits(int priority)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> master(cv_m);
        if(priority == 1){
            
            cv.wait(master); 
            std::cout<<"cv.wait(master);"<<std::endl;
        }
        else {
         cv1.wait(master);  
         std::cout<<"cv1.wait(master);"<<std::endl;
        }
        std::cout<<"priority"<<priority<<std::endl;
        master.unlock();
}
 
void signals(int priority)
{
    switch (priority){
            case 1:
                std::cout<<"both notifyall"<<std::endl;
                cv.notify_all();
                cv1.notify_all(); 
                break;

            case 2:
                std::cout<<"single notifyall"<<std::endl;
                cv1.notify_all();
                break;
        }
}
 
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(waits,1), t2(waits,2), t3(waits,1), t4(signals,2),t5(signals,1);
    t1.join(); 
    t2.join(); 
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
    t5.join();

}```
````

Comment: `notify_all` doesn't mean "notify every thread under the sun". It means "notify all threads that currently wait on this condition variable". You have two condition variables, and the threads use `priority` to choose which of them to wait on.

Comment: That said, the output you observe is basically accidental. Since `t4` is created before `t5`, it would in practice usually get to run first - but that's not guaranteed, it's possible that `t5` would beat it and notify all threads, and then they'd all wake up in essentially random order.

Comment: As both the condition variable is waiting for a lock "master" , so once the lock is available won't the threads in wait by both condtion variable will try to acquire the lock ?

Comment: No, that's not how condition variables work at all. Condition variables don't wait on locks. Rather, threads wait on condition variables; then, when the condition variable is notified, it re-acquires the lock before allowing the thread to proceed. There's no special relationship between two condition variables that happen to want to acquire the same lock.

Comment: ahha , It makes sense now to me . Thank you very much @IgorTandetnik

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Please answer in the answer section. At the moment, this question is orphaned.